# Upgrade docker on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, docker, centos7

I'm running centos 7 and have installed docker on host using epel packages:

```
yum install epel-release
yum install docker
```

But the docker version is-`Docker version 0.11.1-dev, build 02d20af/0.11.1`

The latest stable branch of docker is 1.2

I'm running couple of containers on this host, so how can i update docker safely on this host?

yum update docker does not update to the latest version as the epel repo has old package.

Comment: Here is another answer on how to install Docker 1.5 on CentOS 7:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28961080/how-to-install-the-latest-version-of-docker-on-centos-7

Answer (score 40, accepted):

<del>Note that current stable version of Docker is actually 1.3, not 1.2.</del> See the [Docker release notes](https://docs.docker.com/release-notes/) to discover the latest version.

Before upgrading your docker host, you might want to backup some of the docker images you have, especially those issued from the `docker commit` command. To do so, take a look at the [docker export](http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#export) command.
You might also want to backup your containers' volumes. For that take a look at the [Docker user guide on data volumes](http://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes).

Once you are confident you have all the backups you need for an eventual fresh start you can move on upgrading your Docker daemon.

On the [Docker installation guide for CentOS 7](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/centos/#/install-with-yum), <del>it is advised to install docker from the [binaries](https://docs.docker.com/installation/binaries/) if you want the latest. I suggest you follow those instructions to install the latest docker.</del> **Docker now provides updates through the `yum` package manager.**

Once done with that use the `docker images` command to verify if you still have your Docker images and `docker ps` to check your containers. If some are missing, recreate them from your backups.

If you created docker images from custom Dockerfiles, you also want to rebuild those images to check that no Dockerfile has issues with the new Docker daemon. There is a [big gap](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) between Docker 0.11.1 and 1.3 and fixes and new features were brought to the Dockerfiles syntax.

---

In details here are the commands to run once you are ready to upgrade docker:

```
# stop the docker service
$ sudo service docker stop

# download the latest docker binary and replace the current outdated docker
# DEPRECATED WAY TO UPGRADE DOCKER: $ sudo wget https://get.docker.com/builds/Linux/x86_64/docker-latest -O /usr/bin/docker
$ sudo yum update docker-engine

# start the docker service
$ sudo service docker start

# check the version
$ sudo docker version

# check the images and containers
$ sudo docker images
$ sudo docker ps
$ sudo docker ps -a
```

Comment: If I uninstall docker (the one installed through yum) will the images still be there are will they be purged?

Comment: I was able to upgrade docker on CentOS 7 without loosing the images or containers. I edited my answer with the commands I used to upgrade docker. Note that you still need to have backups just in case you have difficulties.

Comment: **Warning!!** This answer destroys Docker on CentOS! The latest file is a 404 Error! Don't use it!

Comment: Thank you for the heads up! I edited my answer so that the upgrade is now done using `yum`

Comment: i agree with you.. this is already destroy docker on my server.

Comment: @thomasleveil please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67942974/centos-8-how-to-update-docker-client

Comment: <sudo yum update docker-engine> this command is not recognized. <sudo yum upgrade docker*> this works.

Answer (score 50):

## Update to upgrade docker CentOS 7.4

```
sudo yum remove docker docker-client docker-client-latest docker-common docker-latest docker-latest-logrotate docker-logrotate docker-selinux  docker-engine-selinux docker-engine
sudo yum install -y yum-utils device-mapper-persistent-data lvm2
sudo yum-config-manager --add-repo https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo
sudo yum install docker-ce


sudo systemctl start docker
sudo systemctl enable docker
sudo systemctl status docker
```

## Refer:

https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/centos/

Comment: Do not use this instruction if you are unsure. You can lose docker having error on `yum install docker-ce` step: Package: docker-ce-18.06.0.ce-3.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable) Requires: container-selinux >= 2.9

Comment: This was the command I just ran and it seems to have worked:
`yum update docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io`

Comment: this worked for me and the accepted answer did not

Answer (score 8):

try these commands:

```
sudo yum update -y
```

stop docker before upgrade

```
sudo service docker stop
sudo yum upgrade docker*
```

start it again

```
sudo service docker start
```

check the version

```
sudo docker version
```

Comment: what about `yum update -y` before everything

Comment: It would be a good idea :)

Answer (score 0):

You can install docker using repo or a package file as below:

```
yum install -y yum-utils

yum-config-manager --add-repo https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo

yum install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-compose-plugin
```

Verify that the fingerprint matches `060A 61C5 1B55 8A7F 742B 77AA C52F EB6B 621E 9F35` and accept the GPG key if requested to do so.

For the installation of a particular version, you can refer tothe command below :

```
yum list docker-ce --showduplicates | sort -r
```

So you may use the command above with the installation instruction for the docker upgradation process.

OR

Installation steps using the package download Visit this link: https://download.docker.com/linux/centos Then select your preferred CentOS version. Once you've found the.rpm file for the Docker version you wish to instal, navigate to x86 64/stable/Packages/.
So to upgrade the docker using package downloading instead of repository add, you can use `yum -y upgrade` and point it to the new file.